# Prove that the derivative exists

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $g$ be differentiable on an open interval $I$ and let 
$f(x) = g(x)d(x)$,
where $d(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $d(x)=0$ otherwise. Let $a\in I$ be a zero of $g$.
Then prove that $f'(a)$ exists if and only if $a$ is a zero of $g'$.

My professor gave a hint that I am supposed to use two sequences to solve this problem, but I am not sure how to use sequences to demonstrate differentiability. Am I supposed to create a sequence involving rational numbers and another involving irrationals?

Thanks!

Comment: Given an arbitrary sequence, you can decompose it in two subsequences, one of rational terms and the other of irrational ones. Of course I'm assuming the sequence has infinite rational and irrational terms. The other possibilities are sequences consisting purely of rational or irrational terms, except for a finite number of terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of considering a sequence of rationals and a sequence of irrationals is a good idea. The key is that the limit definition of the derivative should hold for any sequence of points approaching $a$.

---

Suppose $f'(a)$ exists. By considering the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(q_n)-f(a)}{q_n-a}$ for a sequence of irrationals $q_n$ that converges to $a$, we see that $f'(a)=0$. This implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(r_n)-f(a)}{r_n-a}$ is also $0$ for a sequence of rationals $r_n$ converging to $a$. But this latter limit equals $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(r_n) - g(a)}{r_n-a}$ which equals $g'(a)$.

---

Suppose $g'(a)=0$. Since $f(a)=g(a)=0$ and $|f(x)| \le |g(x)|$ for any $x$, we have
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right|
\le \frac{|f(x)|}{|x-a|}
\le \frac{|g(x)|}{|x-a|}.$$
Since the right-hand side converges to $g'(a)=0$ as $x \to a$, we see that $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = 0$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Assume that $ g'(a)=0$.
$$(\forall x\in I) \;\; |d(x)| \le 1\implies$$
$$(\forall x\in I-\{a\})\;\; |\frac{f(x)}{x-a}|\le |\frac{g(x)}{x-a}|$$
So
$$g'(a)=0\implies$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{x-a}=0\implies$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}=0\implies$$
$$f'(a)=0$$

Conversely
$$f'(a) \text{ exists }\; \implies$$
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)d(x)}{x-a} \in \Bbb R \implies$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{g(a_n)d(a_n)}{a_n-a}\in \Bbb R$$
choose $ a_n $ such that
$$a_n\in \Bbb Q \text{ and } \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=a$$
you can take
$$a_n=\frac{\lfloor 10^na\rfloor}{10^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(a)=0$, we have $f(a)=0$.

---

I. To prove: $g'(a)=0\Rightarrow$ $f'(a)$ exists.

Suppose that $g'(a)=0$. We have
that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)d(x)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}d(x).
\end{eqnarray*}
However, for $x\neq a$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\frac{g(x)d(x)}{x-a}\right| & = & \left|\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\right||d(x)|\\
 & \leq & \left|\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\right|\\
 & \rightarrow & g'(a)\\
 & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
as $x\rightarrow a$. By sandwich rule, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)d(x)}{x-a}$
exists and equals to $0$. Therefore, $f'(a)$ exists and equals to
zero.

---

II. To prove $f'(a)$ exists $\Rightarrow g'(a)=0$.

Conversely, suppose that $f'(a)$ exists. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(a) & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}d(x).
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can choose a sequence
$(x_{n})$ in $I\cap\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow a$ and
$x_{n}\neq a$ for all $n$. Observe that $d(x_{n})=1$ for all $n$.
We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(a) & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}d(x)\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(x_{n})-g(a)}{x_{n}-a}d(x_{n})\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(x_{n})-g(a)}{x_{n}-a}\\
 & = & g'(a).
\end{eqnarray*}
Also notice that $\mathbb{Q}^{c}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so we can
choose another sequence $(y_{n})$ in $I\cap\mathbb{Q}^{c}$ such
that $y_{n}\rightarrow a$ and $y_{n}\neq a$. Observe that $d(y_{n})=0$
for all $n$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(a) & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}d(x)\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(y_{n})-g(a)}{y_{n}-a}d(y_{n})\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $g'(a)=f'(a)=0$.